Why iPhone 6S & iPad Pro (2015) do not connect to WPA3 network?
Working with my ISP with whom I have a 1000/300 Mbps fibre network to find out why my download speed is stuck at 20 Mbps, they tried by changing the Security from WPA 2 Personal to WPA 3 Personal.
Besides this not solving the issue, it also caused both my partner's devices (an iPhone 6S Plus and a 9.7" iPad Pro, heroically still working, and beautifully well!) to be "Unable to join this network".
Resetting Network Settings and restarting the devices had no effect.
Restoring the WPA 2 Personal security protocol also restored connectivity.
My question is: are these devices unable to use that protocol? Is there any way around this?

Yes, those devices do not support WPA 3.
From Secure access to wireless networks - Apple Support:

WPA3 is supported on the following Apple devices:

iPhone 7 or later
iPad 5th generation or later
[...]


The iPad 5th generation was released in 2017, so the iPad in question would not be compatible either.
